# Control what happens when associated file is opened

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have an application made in C#.NET with VS2010, with which I have associated my file extensions, by using the `Publish` tab in project properties. However, when I open the file, all it does is simply open my application on my main form. How can I control what happens when the file opens, e.g. open a certain form, and put the file contents in a richTextBox?

Comment: Opening from a file association will open your application with a parameter passed to it (the full path of the file you want to open). You need to get this parameter in your form and act accordingly. See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1241440/2609288

Comment: Use the argument passed to your Main() method or use the Environment.CommandLine property.  It contains the path to the file that was clicked.